# How to connect a 2.4ghz 4ch RC receiver to a brushed dc motor controller?

Tags: motor-controller, remote-control, brushed-dc-motor

I currently have a 36vbdc 800w motor connected to a 36v 800w motor speed controller (similar to what they use to control ebikes) just like this one: https://aws.robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/919811586_739.jpg (I don't know how to upload pics or wiring diagrams to my question or I would).
[image: image of motor speed controller]

I would like to use a 2.4ghz 4ch RC remote transmitter and receiver to control the motor speed instead of the wired throttle I currently use, which is a 3pin hall sensor (+5v, Gnd, sensor) twist throttle.

Is there any way to connect the RC receiver to the motor controller to use the remote transmitter to control motor speed? How would I go about this?

I believe both the RC signal and the hall sensor are PWM, but do I need a receiver board to interface with the RC receiver and the motor controller?

Would I need to implement arduino into the equation?

Comment: Tip: 'GHz' or gigahertz, 'V' or volt, 'W' or watt. Capitals matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RC servo signal is a 1-2ms pulse with repetition period of ~20ms. Ebike controllers generally accept an analog voltage between 0-5V (with 1V=off and 4V = full throttle). You will need an interface to convert from one to the other. Possible solutions range from purely mechanical (servo attached to a potentiometer) to an MCU with D/A converter.

The Arduino can measure servo pulse width with [pulseIn()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.PulseIn) and produce an 'analog' output with [analogWrite()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/). On most Arduinos the analog outputs are actually 0-100% PWM at ~490Hz. To convert this to true analog you need a low pass filter or integrator which averages the pulses, eg. this simple [RC filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit):-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUBGw2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A side effect of integrating the PWM pulses is slower throttle response. Here is the result of simulating the above circuit in [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/), with a 0.5 second 50% throttle burst:-

[image]

Comment: Bruce, But arduino can't take that much current...

Comment: Bruce, Also, where is the RC receiver in your schematic?

Comment: "But arduino can't take that much current..." - that's OK, the motor controller doesn't take that much current on its throttle input.

Comment: "where is the RC receiver in your schematic" - sorry the receiver connections seemed so obvious I didn't bother putting them in the diagram. Each channel has 3 pins: Signal, +5V, and Ground. Connect +5V and Ground to same on Arduino. Connect Signal to the Arduino pin you are reading with pulseIn().  Here's an example:- http://stormgate.org/tricopter/receivercircuit.jpg

Comment: Bruce, sorry I'm new to all of this so I apologize if my questions seem obvious or remedial. Having said that, I'm still a little confused... So the 3 hall sensor (throttle) wires from the motor controller (instead of connecting to the twist throttle) would connect to the arduino, and the 3 pins from the RC receiver would also connect to the arduino?

Comment: Bruce,  I have read up some on the arduino builds and I keep seeing something about a motor shield board being used, does my motor controller already serve that function? Or do I need one of those too? Also, can you possibly tell me which arduino (uno, mega, nano, etc...) that I would need to use? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: "So the 3 hall sensor (throttle) wires from the motor controller (instead of connecting to the twist throttle) would connect to the arduino, and the 3 pins from the RC receiver would also connect to the arduino?" - Yes. You already have a motor controller so you don't need a shield (the Arduino is only used to convert the RC servo pulse to analog 0-5V). Any AVR based **5V** Arduino should be OK. I use Nano clones because they are small and lightweight, breadboard friendly, and very cheap! (2-3$ on eBay).

Comment: OK I think I've mostly got a grasp on it. I just have one more question for you for now: Can you possibly tell me what code I would use to program the arduino nano and where I might be able to find it? Ps Thank you very much for answering my question and for all the info, I very much appreciate it!

Comment: [RC reciever to analog 0-5 voltage](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=126604.0)